# After setting a format and writing some values for a given range, that same format is partially and automatically applied to other ranges

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm not sure if this is an issue or if it is expected behavior from Excel. If it is indeed expected behavior, I would appreciate an explanation about what is happening, since I cannot see a pattern.

If you set a format and some values to a range and then assign only values to another range located below the first one, the format of the first range is applied partially (randomly?) to the new range.

My test function:

```
   function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

 function loadSampleData(applyFormat) {
    var columnCount = 30;
    if (applyFormat) {
        columnCount = 5;
    }
    var data = [];
    for (var rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++) {
        var row = [];
        for (var columns = 0; columns < columnCount; columns++) {
            var value = columns;
            if (getRandomInt(1, 3) == 2) {
                value = "text";
            }
            row.push(value);
        }
        data.push(row);
    }
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().load(['rowCount', 'columnCount']);
        var extendedRange;
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            var totalRows = data.length;
            var totalColumns = data[0].length;
            var deltaRows = totalRows - selectedRange.rowCount;
            var deltaColumns = totalColumns - selectedRange.columnCount;
            extendedRange = selectedRange.getResizedRange(deltaRows, deltaColumns);
            if (applyFormat) {
                extendedRange.format.fill.color = "orange";
                extendedRange.format.font.color = "white";
            }
            else {
                extendedRange.clear();
            }
            extendedRange.values = data;
        }).then(ctx.sync)
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Steps:

1. Create one button (Button A) in the task pane. This button must call loadSampleData and pass true, to write some data and format (fill and font color) to a range. (Range A)
2. Create another button (Button B) in the task pane. This button must call loadSampleData and pass false, to write only data (no format) to a bigger range (Range B).
3. Click the A1 cell, then click Button A. Notice the range and format that appears.
4. Click A6, then click Button B. Notice that a bigger range is written and that some of its cells have the same format as the range in step 3, even though no explicit format was set to the range.
5. With A6 still selected, click Button B multiple times. Notice that as the values of the range change, the formatted cells change as well.

Notes:

- This doesn't happen if Range B is written above Range A.
- This doesn't happen if Range B is written 4 (or more) rows below Range A.

Thanks!

Comment: First and foremost question:  if you take out the programmability aspect and do these same steps in the regular user interface, like a typical Excel user -- do you see the same behavior?

Comment: The programmability model is based on automation of what the user could do.  So if it's a regular Excel behavior, the program behavior will adopt it.  If you want something different, figure out what you'd do as a user to achieve the desired behavior (e.g., clear formatting on the target range first)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thanks for your comments. If I do this "manually" (paste a small range of values, change its format, then paste a bigger range of values below it) I don't see the behavior. 
Also, in my loadSampleData function above, I'm clearing the range before writing the values, for the case where I want a range without formatting., that is what confuses me the most.

Comment: sorry for the delay.  To make it easier to debug this, any chance you could create a Script Lab snippet and share it as a public Gist?  See https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import.  FWIW, I think the tool will be valuable for you in every-day use as well, for trying out quick API things.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft I didn't know about Script Lab, I think it is great!! Here is the Gist: https://gist.github.com/maalsol/23c7b679a2365bc58efa60f856ed31b7

By the way, you book has been extremely useful as well, great material.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, it's quite a fascinating find!  Let me pass it along to one of our team members to investigate, and we'll update this thread when we have more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fascinatingly, I can reproduce the issue even in the UI, without programmability.  Excel is doing some sort of pattern-matching, though I'll admit I have a hard time deciphering what the pattern is...

[image]

I will discuss with our team -- but in terms of concrete guidance, I think your safest bet is to set the values, and then clear the formatting.  If you want to be super-careful, you can even take it one step further:

1. Set number formatting (to ensure that strings vs numbers vs date strings get interpreted as you want them to be)
2. Set the values
3. `range.clear(Excel.ClearApplyTo.formats);`
4. Re-set the number formatting

I will admit that this seems like a workflow worth improving.  Let me see if we can either fix "values", or provide a method that lets you set values and number formats in one go, and in a stricter fashion than what is happening today.

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice and clear the format after setting the values.